# Use default values from web.config when using web deploy parameters

Tags: asp.net, .net, visual-studio-2012, deployment

I am trying to improve the development and deployment experience in our company by trying to limit the overhead in using multiple environments. We currently have 3 environments: *Debug*, *Test*, *Release*. This means I have multiple configuration files: `web.Debug.config`, `web.Test.config`, `web.Release.config`.

We are using NuGet packages to deploy the internally developed libraries. The library itself is responsible for the configuration values it uses. This is easily done with [NuGet transformation files](http://docs.nuget.org/docs/creating-packages/configuration-file-and-source-code-transformations). Thus, when adding a package to a project, the correct environment transformation file is applied to the correct .config file. Using SlowCheetah and some manual modifications to the csproj file, this works quite well. When switching the build configuration during development, the correct .config file is used; when creating a deployment package it also uses the correct .config file.

The problem arises when I want to use a `parameters.xml` file to allow the release manager to change the configuration values when deploying. ([How to: Use Web Deploy Parameters in a Web Deployment Package](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff398068%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)) He sometimes wants to set up a separate environment to do be able to test certain things, whilst not disturbing the existing test environment.

In theory, the use of a parameters file is the perfect solution. In reality it seems the parameters file is not capable of using the configuration values from the corresponding configuration file when no values are passed. This means that, when we provide a parameters file, we must define the actual default values for each possible replacement value. And of course, this complicates things as their is only one parameters file for all configurations. Always specifying every configuration value when deploying is also not preferred, because this means that, when a configuration value changes, we must change it in two places: the NuGet package and the deployment script which deploys to the default environments.

What would be the easiest way to solve our problem? How can we tell the web deploy wizard to use the default values from the .config file generated when creating the deployment package if no value is filled in?

Answer (score 0):

I have been struggling with this issue as well, The best solution I can come up with is to add parameters via the .pubxml files for each deployment, this means a duplication of efforts unfortunately(Surely someone has a better approach?)